# Backup SqlServer to a FTP-folder

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

Is it possible to let SQL Server 2008 make a backup to a FTP-folder.

I know it's possible to specify as the backup target in SSMS an UNC-path. But is there also the possibility to specify an FTP-Folder (inclusive user name an pwd)? If yes, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably need to write an app in conjunction with a T-SQL script to do this, as there is nothing native to SQL server to backup to FTP.

EDIT: Something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/BackupDBtoFTP.aspx).

Comment: An app or only a TSQL-Script? Is it possible with TSQL?

Comment: Most likely a combination of both.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://sqlbackupandftp.com/